# Active Admin: Creating a Page in Rails by Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I just want to know whether an Admin can create a new page like about_us or something similar to that from admin's page in Rails.
He should be able to create a new view, controller and model{not necessary}.
If this is possible please give me some link for it tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Active Admin` gem creates default UI for data administrators:

> Active Admin is a Ruby on Rails plugin for generating administration
>   style interfaces. It abstracts common business application patterns to
>   make it simple for **developers** to implement beautiful and elegant
>   interfaces with very little effort.

It is *not* like Joomla admin pages, which allows the admin to change/add the pages users can see, unless their are data-driven in an application specifically written to enable that.

You can look for libraries which solve this problem, or integrate rails with a CMS application (like this: http://joomlarails.com/)